# jquery touchstart on checkbox can't trigger an overlay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, overlay

I'm new to jQuery and html (only react before).

Right now I want to trigger an overlay when I touch a checkbox on touch devices.

Actually I have had finished this function(worked perfectly), but after some operation(like git commit or something else I dont know), the function suddenly couldn't work at all(the overlay cant show up).

I have spent the whole night to trying to debug. I think it must be some small mistake I made(like a wrong closing tag or something like this), but I cant find out.

Here is my code:

```js
$(function(){
    $('div.touch-checkbox').on('click touchstart', function(e) {
// e.stopPropagation();
 if (console && console.log) console.log('hi');
 $('.paulund_modal').paulund_modal_box();
    });
});


//the modal
(function($){
    $.fn.paulund_modal_box = function(prop){

 var options = $.extend({
     height : "250",
     width : "300",
     title:"Please select your time",
     description: "",
     top : ($(window).outerHeight() / 4) + 'px',
     left : (($(window).width() - 300) / 2) + 'px',
 },prop);
 if (console && console.log) console.log($(window).width());
 return this.click(function(){
        //this line of console log didn't run
     if (console && console.log) console.log('hi11');
     add_block_page();
     add_popup_box();
     add_styles();
     $('.paulund_modal_box').fadeIn();
 });

 function add_styles(){
     $('.paulund_modal_box').css({
  'position':'absolute',
  'left':options.left,
  'top':options.top,
  'display':'none',
  'height': options.height + 'px',
  'width': options.width + 'px',
  'border':'1px solid #fff',
  'box-shadow': '0px 2px 7px #292929',
  '-moz-box-shadow': '0px 2px 7px #292929',
  '-webkit-box-shadow': '0px 2px 7px #292929',
  'border-radius':'10px',
  '-moz-border-radius':'10px',
  '-webkit-border-radius':'10px',
  'background': '#f2f2f2',
  'z-index':'50',
     });
     $('.paulund_modal_close').css({
  'position':'relative',
  'top':'0px',
  'left':'20px',
  'float':'right',
  'font-size':'20px',
  'display':'block',
  'height':'50px',
  'width':'50px',
     });
     $('.paulund_modal_close').html(
  '<i class="fa fa-times"></i>'
     );
            /*Block page overlay*/
     var pageHeight = $(document).height();
     var pageWidth = $(window).width();

     $('.paulund_block_page').css({
  'position':'absolute',
  'top':'0',
  'left':'0',
  'background-color':'rgba(0,0,0,0.6)',
  'height':pageHeight,
  'width':pageWidth,
  'z-index':'10'
     });
     $('.paulund_inner_modal_box').css({
  'background-color':'#fff',
  'height':(options.height - 50) + 'px',
  'width':(options.width - 50) + 'px',
  'padding':'10px',
  'margin':'15px',
  'border-radius':'10px',
  '-moz-border-radius':'10px',
  '-webkit-border-radius':'10px'
     });
 }

 function add_block_page(){
     var block_page = $('<div class="paulund_block_page"></div>');

     $(block_page).appendTo('body');
 }

 function add_popup_box(){
     var pop_up = $('<div class="paulund_modal_box"><a href="#" class="paulund_modal_close"></a><div class="paulund_inner_modal_box"><h3>' + options.title + '</h3><p>' + options.description + '</p> <div><p>hello</p></div></div></div>');
     $(pop_up).appendTo('.paulund_block_page');

     $('.paulund_modal_close').click(function(){
  $(this).parent().fadeOut().remove();
  $('.paulund_block_page').fadeOut().remove();
     });
 }

 return this;
    };

})(jQuery);
```

```css
.touch-checkbox{
    z-index:3;
    height:11px;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .5s ease;
    transition: all .5s ease;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>test</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="description" content="First time using jQuery">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0001">
  <link href="style/screen.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></scrip\
t>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/checkbox-touch-device.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="portrait">
        <div class="paulund_modal"></div>
        <p>hello</p>
        <div class="touch-checkbox">
            <input id="sun12am" type="checkbox"> <label for="sun12am"></label>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, I want to give class `.touch-checkbox` a on click trigger(I only use `touchstart` with media query in my local dev environment, use click here for Code Snippets.).

the code until `if (console && console.log) console.log($(window).width());` in JS file is useful, but cant return the overlay.

I guess there is something wrong with `return this.click(function()` in the JS file.

I'm sure this code did work at the beginning, I just wonder why it can't work at all without modifying(maybe I modified it by mistake but I didn't recognized)......

Can someone help me? thank you sooooo much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a need of return. Remove the return statement and run **`$('.paulund_modal_box').fadeIn()`**

> The return statement stops the execution of a function and returns a
>   value from that function.
>
> ***[See here for more explanation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return)***

```js
$(function() {
  $('div.touch-checkbox').on('click touchstart', function(e) {
    // e.stopPropagation();
    if (console && console.log) console.log('hi');
    $('.paulund_modal').paulund_modal_box();
  });
});


//the modal
(function($) {
  $.fn.paulund_modal_box = function(prop) {
    var options = $.extend({
      height: "250",
      width: "300",
      title: "Please select your time",
      description: "",
      top: ($(window).outerHeight() / 4) + 'px',
      left: (($(window).width() - 300) / 2) + 'px',
    }, prop);
    if (console && console.log)
      console.log($(window).width());
    //this line of console log didn't run
    if (console && console.log) console.log('hi11');
    add_block_page();
    add_popup_box();
    add_styles();
    $('.paulund_modal_box').fadeIn();

    function add_styles() {
      $('.paulund_modal_box').css({
        'position': 'absolute',
        'left': options.left,
        'top': options.top,
        'display': 'none',
        'height': options.height + 'px',
        'width': options.width + 'px',
        'border': '1px solid #fff',
        'box-shadow': '0px 2px 7px #292929',
        '-moz-box-shadow': '0px 2px 7px #292929',
        '-webkit-box-shadow': '0px 2px 7px #292929',
        'border-radius': '10px',
        '-moz-border-radius': '10px',
        '-webkit-border-radius': '10px',
        'background': '#f2f2f2',
        'z-index': '50',
      });
      $('.paulund_modal_close').css({
        'position': 'relative',
        'top': '0px',
        'left': '20px',
        'float': 'right',
        'font-size': '20px',
        'display': 'block',
        'height': '50px',
        'width': '50px',
      });
      $('.paulund_modal_close').html(
        '<i class="fa fa-times"></i>'
      );
      /*Block page overlay*/
      var pageHeight = $(document).height();
      var pageWidth = $(window).width();

      $('.paulund_block_page').css({
        'position': 'absolute',
        'top': '0',
        'left': '0',
        'background-color': 'rgba(0,0,0,0.6)',
        'height': pageHeight,
        'width': pageWidth,
        'z-index': '10'
      });
      $('.paulund_inner_modal_box').css({
        'background-color': '#fff',
        'height': (options.height - 50) + 'px',
        'width': (options.width - 50) + 'px',
        'padding': '10px',
        'margin': '15px',
        'border-radius': '10px',
        '-moz-border-radius': '10px',
        '-webkit-border-radius': '10px'
      });
    }

    function add_block_page() {
      var block_page = $('<div class="paulund_block_page"></div>');

      $(block_page).appendTo('body');
    }

    function add_popup_box() {
      var pop_up = $('<div class="paulund_modal_box"><a href="#" class="paulund_modal_close"></a><div class="paulund_inner_modal_box"><h3>' + options.title + '</h3><p>' + options.description + '</p> <div><p>hello</p></div></div></div>');
      $(pop_up).appendTo('.paulund_block_page');

      $('.paulund_modal_close').click(function() {
        $(this).parent().fadeOut().remove();
        $('.paulund_block_page').fadeOut().remove();
      });
    }

    return this;
  };

})(jQuery);
```

```css
.touch-checkbox {
  z-index: 3;
  height: 11px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
  -o-transition: all .5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .5s ease;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div id="portrait">
  <div class="paulund_modal"></div>
  <p>hello</p>
  <div class="touch-checkbox">
    <input id="sun12am" type="checkbox"> <label for="sun12am"></label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: oh my god, Thank you so much!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!  I'm not fully understand jquery at this time, can I ask when should I need that return statement? The function did work with that return statement some time before...

Comment: @Larry.Z The return statement stops the execution of a function and returns a value from that function. [**See here for more explanation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return)